# Making a for loop for two variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, simulation, bayesian

I have a dataset on fecal egg counts (FEC) in sheep and would like to test the effect of different treatments. I have 120 farms treated with combination of different drugs. I am using the "eggcount" package that is based on the Bayesian approach to simulate and produce the outputs for each farm and treatment (Drug).

I want to make a loop for two variables; i) Farm and ii) Drug.
This means the for loop can generate the output for each farm and drug, similar to the subset function.

```
setwd("C:/Data")
dat <- read.csv("McMaster_UTC.csv", header=T, sep="'", na.string=NA)
dat$EPG1 <- as.numeric(dat$EPG1)
dat$EPG2 <- as.numeric(dat$EPG2)

# subset for Fram & Drug: if I want to run the data for each Farm and Drug. I assume with a loop I don't #need the subset function.
dat1 <-subset(dat, Farm==1 & Drug=="CLO", select=1:9)

# A model to compare the two groups (unpaired)
model <- fecr_stan(egg.1$EPG1/50, egg.1$EPG2/50, rawCounts=FALSE, paired=FALSE, indEfficacy=FALSE)

#This is the for loop that I have in my mind, but not sure how to fit these in the loop:
out <- vectro()
for(i in 1:ncol(dat)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(dat)) {
....
....
set.seed(1234)
model <- fecr_stan(egg.1$EPG1/50, egg.1$EPG2/50, rawCounts=FALSE, paired=FALSE, indEfficacy=FALSE)

    model[i] <- out[i]
```

## Here is a subset of my data:

[Sample data for 2 farms with two drugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqgmf.png)

Comment: So what's stopping you?  I'm not grasping what your actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you just want to loop over each combination of `Farm` and `Drug`. Step 1 would be to work out what the levels of each of these factors are. Given you have read your CSV file without `stringsAsFactors` set to `FALSE`, we can get the levels using the `levels` function:

```
Farms = levels(dat$Farm)
Drugs = levels(dat$Drug)
```

Then to loop over each, you can just do:

```
set.seed(1234) ## Only put this inside your loop if you want to use the same
               ## sequence of random numbers for each model.  
for(farm in Farms){
  for(drug in Drugs){
    dat1 <-subset(dat, Farm == farm & Drug == drug, select=1:9)
    model <- fecr_stan(dat1$EPG1/50, dat1$EPG2/50, 
                       rawCounts = TRUE, paired=FALSE, 
                       indEfficacy=FALSE)

   ## Note you'll have to do something to save or store the model output here
  }
}
```

Thanks James for your codes/comments, much appreciated. First; there are a couple of errors in my codes:  `egg.1$EPG1/50 and egg.1$EPG1/50` should be `dat$EPG1/50 & dat$EPG1/50`. I must say that I am not good with loops, just in case if I am asking silly questions here. Yes, I want to compare the difference between dat$EPG1/50 & dat$EPG2/50 for each Drug within each Farm, and save the output in a vector. When you say "loop over each", what do you mean by that? Are you suggesting that I put `model <- fecr_stan(dat$EPG1/50, dat$EPG2/50, rawCounts=TRUE, paired=FALSE, indEfficacy=FALSE)`, and it will work? Should I put the `setseed(12345)` outside the loop? I appreciate having your thoughts! I attached a sample of my data as an image, if you want to have a look. I didn't know how I can paste a sample of my data here.

Comment: @Ahmad - does it do what you want to do?

Comment: @Ahmad - I've altered the code to include some of the steps. `for` loops in R are more of the "iterate over elements of a list/vector" type (and are sometimes called `foreach` loops in other languages), then traditional "increment a counter" type `for` loops. So `for(drug in Drugs)` will step through each of the levels of the factor which are stored in `Drugs` etc.

Comment: Thanks, James, I used your codes in the loop. I created a vector ```out <- NA``` (outside the loop) to save the output and put this ```out[farm, drug] <- model``` inside the loop as you suggested. It worked ok (no error)- but didn't produce an output to be saved in the vector ```out```. Your thoughts?  I will keep working on it to see how I can make it work.

Comment: I also noticed that ```Farms = levels(dat$Farm)``` didn't work as expcted and generated ```NULL``` ??

Comment: Hi @Ahmad. Try typing `is.factor(dat$Farm)` after you have read the data in. If it returns `FALSE`, then you have two options. Either turn it into a factor `dat$Farm = factor(dat$Farm)`, or instead of using the levels,just use the unique values of `Farm`, i.e. `Farms = sort(unique(dat$Farm))`

Comment: Thanks James, I noticed even with Fram as a numeric variable in the data, I had to convert it to a factor. I will try this to see if this will generate an output. Thanks again!