# Batch plotting across multiple columns using variable pairs from another 2 columns

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, dplyr

Example data:

```
structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                        2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 
                        2020, 2020), 
               type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
               levels = c("Brand","Shop", "Retail"), class = "factor"), 
               sub_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
              levels = c("Ambient", "Food", "Drink", "Grocery", "non-grocery", "non-drink","Food"), class = "factor"), 
              
data_column_1 = c(14, 11, 42, 68, 1, 0, 30, 20, 75, 23, 16, 0, 15, 0, 46, 26, 42, 19, 56, 0),
data_column_2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  NA_real_), 
data_column_3 = c(198, 527, 0, 224, 176, 0, 322, 2, 564, 973, 506, 0, 569, 0, 452, 422, 456, 720, 255, 0), 
data_column_4 = c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 56, NA_real_, NA_real_, 62,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
data_column_5 = c(1600, 206, 150,36, 0, 0, 702, 263, 0, 1124, 215, 68,718, 0, 1938, 584, 0, 652, 181,67)), 

class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2018,2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020), sigtype = structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
levels = c("Brand", "Shop","Retail"), class = "factor"), 
.rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:6,7:9, 10:13, 14L, 15:17, 18:20), 
ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I would like to produce a series of plots, year on the x and then iterate through each data_column_(number). However, I would also like for this to run through each type and corresponding sub_type.

So:

Brand & Ambient
Brand & Food
Brand & Drink
Brand & non-drink
Retail & Grocery
Retail & non-drink
etc.

Some sub_types have the same name but different types, but should not be plotted against one another, only within the type.

The best I have managed so far:

```
other.unknown.columns <- colnames(df)
other.unknown.columns <- other.unknown.columns[-c(1,2,3)] # remove year, type, sub_type

setwd("my/filepath")

df$type <- factor(df$sigtype)
df$subtype <- factor(df3$sub_type)

type.levels <- levels(df$type)
sub_type.levels <- levels(df$sub_type)

for (i in type.levels) {
    
  workingData <- subset(df, type == i) # this was an attempt to only have one type present, therefore to not iterate through unnecessary sub_types

    for (j in sub_type.levels) {
      
          for(k in other.unknown.columns){
            
           g <-  ggplot(workingData, aes(x=year, y=.data[[k]])) +
                geom_line() +
                geom_point() +
                ggtitle(heading)
           print(g)
      
      dev.off()         
            
      filename<-paste(i, "_", j, "_", k, ".png", sep="")
      png(filename = filename, width=720) 
      heading<-paste(i," sub_type ",j," - ", k)
      
      
  }
 }
}

dev.list()
dev.off()
```

However, this produces every possible mixture of type and sub_type, and the data is not from the correct columns / has multiple points per year.

[See incorrect example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h0ut.png) Intentionally cut off axis title and heading due to data sensitivity from my actual data.

I also sometimes run into issues with dev.off depending on how I alter the code, so I placed the extra dev at the bottom to quit out.

Other threads I have reviewed that have helped me get this far:

[Making a for loop for two variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113505/making-a-for-loop-for-two-variables-in-r)

[Why does dev.new() open RStudioGD- and png device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69587289/why-does-dev-new-open-rstudiogd-and-png-device)

[Code to clear all plots in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640016/code-to-clear-all-plots-in-rstudio)

[Loop through multiple columns and make a plot (with error bars for each plot) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124115/loop-through-multiple-columns-and-make-a-plot-with-error-bars-for-each-plot-in)

Comment: Would facets work? Easiest approach in ggplot2: `df |>  pivot_longer(-c(1:3)) |>   ggplot(aes(year, value, color = name)) +  geom_line() + geom_point() +  facet_wrap(~type + sub_type)`

Comment: Hi Jon, that has produced the facet wrap quite well, thank you!

It's not a solution to the problem of outputting individual plots so I will not mark it as such. Unless you can advice as such?